# Let $D\subset \mathbb R^d$ and suppose that $D\cap K$ has measure zero for every compact $K$. Does $D$ have measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

This is probably either obviously true or obviously false but I have forgotten.

Suppose $D$ does not have measure zero. Let $(U_n)$ be a countable open cover of $\mathbb R^d$ consisting of bounded sets. Then $\mu(D)=\mu(\sum_n D\cap U_n)=\sum_n\mu(D\cap U_n)>0$. So there exists $U_n$ such that $U_n\cap D$ has a positive measure. But since $U_n$ are bounded, we can choose $K$ compact with $U_n\subset K$ compact. This contradicts the statement.

Comment: You don't need a proof by contradiction here. Just use countable additivity and the fact that $\mathbb{R^d}$ has a countable compact cover. (But note that the elements of that cover are not disjoint.)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, based on the comment I will write a solution.

Suppose $D\subset \mathbb R^d$ has the property that $D\cap K$ has measure zero for every compact $K$.

Since $\mathbb R^d$ has a countable compact cover $(K_n)$, using positive addivity of the measure, we have$$\mu(D)=\mu(D\cap\bigcup_nK_n)=\mu(\bigcup_n(D\cap K_n))\leq\sum_n\mu(D\cap K_n)=0.$$